# How can this loop loop 4 times only?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm making a PHP to check for the friends ID in a friends relation table, then returns the info of the friends.
The problem is, the first loop loops 2 times, and that's right, when I check for the value of the count of the second loop, I find it equals to 4, how can this happen and the second table got 4 rows?

Here's the code:

```
   while ($rowres = mysql_fetch_array($listres))
        {
            if ($_GET["ID"] == $rowres["ID"])
            {
                while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
                {
                    $count++;
                     if ($rowres["FID"] == $row["ID"])
                        {

                        }
                }

            }
        }
```

Comment: not sure if lack of your input data wouldn't be helpful

Comment: Show your queries. Why are you pulling new results inside your first ones?

Comment: so this one is wrong? idk how to work with queries that much

Comment: @JoeSKh: typically its wrong, when you find yourself running `select` queries based on the results of another query its usually a sign you should be using a `JOIN`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the inner loop will loop through result only one loop, because after it loops to the last element of $result pointer of result will be point after last element, the easiest way here will be probably reset pointer to the top:

```
while ($rowres = mysql_fetch_array($listres))
        {
            if ($_GET["ID"] == $rowres["ID"])
            {
                mysql_data_seek($result,0);  //<-HERE
                while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
                {
                    $count++;
                     if ($rowres["FID"] == $row["ID"])
                        {

                        }
                }

            }
        }
```

## **please note: mysql extension is *DEPRECATED* and will be removed in the future. Instead use [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)**

Comment: Not necessarily, but id say its not the best implementation, because that would involve some kind of join most likely and laternate logic, but the OP hasnt given enough info to suggest what that implementation would be.

Comment: For example hes got the ID passed from the UI and hes checking it agains the id in another result presumably to see if the user is the same as the one logged in - but if hes got his auth right he should have the logged in users ID in the session somwhere so theres not even a need for the first query... Only for the friends data. If this werent the case then he can jsut select on the ID from get and JOIN it to the friends and do it all in one shot.